# How to decrypt the username in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am having an issue with an application, when am recording the flow in jmeter, username and password is coming in HTTP header manager in encoded format ("TWFuYWdlcjE6cGFzczEyMw=="), I tried to decrypt and parameterize the value by adding Authorization Manger which didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: this value is Base64 encoded, which is normally used in Basic authentication. If you use a Base64 decoder you can see the values you used. What is it you're actually trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see username and password in plain text you can use [__base64Decode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Decodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) available via [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

[image]

[__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) does the opposite thing:

[image]

Check out [How to Use the Custom JMeter Functions Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-custom-jmeter-functions-plugin/) for more information on the above and other custom JMeter functions.

So in order to parameterize the credentials you could:

1. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [`Authorization`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of `Basic ${__base64Encode(Manager1:pass123,)}` where `Manager1` and `pass123` could be [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and provide base URL, and username and password in plain text - the Authorization Manager will automatically generate and add the proper `Authorization Header` to all HTTP Request samplers it its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).